# Select text between two patterns with sed, when the patterns are repeated

Tags: sed, macos

I would like to select the text between two patterns, **when some of the patterns can be repeated** as follows.

Here is the input:

```
Blalala
PAT1
'Omfoem From 
balanf PAT1 This is the
text that I want
to get PAT2: apples
Whatever: oranges
```

Here is the output I would like:

```
This is the
text that I want
to get
```

I have tried using this script (**I am using OSX**):

```
gsed -e 's/PAT1/\nPAT1\n/' -e 's/PAT2/\nPAT2\n/' file1.txt | sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{//!p;}'
```

But it outputs the following:

```
'Omfoem From 
balanf 
PAT1
This is the
text that I want
to get
```

In this particular case, I could apply `sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{//!p;}'` a second time and I would get the right output.

However, I am looking for a script that works in different situations: if any of the patterns is repeated, independently of the number of times, and if the pattern are not repeated at all.

In any of these cases, I would like to be able to extract the text between pattern PAT1 and PAT2 when PAT1 and PAT2 are the closest to each other.

Comment: This is your 5th question so far (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/396175/charlie) and you haven't accepted any answers yet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do when someone answers a question. You REALLY need to get away from trying to use sed for stuff like this, it's simply not the best tool for the job. Tag your question with `awk` if you want to see some reasonable ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be (`POSIX sed`):

```
$ sed -e '
   /PAT1/,/PAT2/!d
   H;/PAT1/h;/PAT2/!d;g
   s/PAT2.*//;s/.*PAT1//
' file
```

Assuming PAT1 and PAT2 are on different lines.

Comment: Specifying the same hard-coded value (e.g. `PAT1`) twice in a program is generally bad coding practice. Specifying it 3 times should REALLY make you reconsider what you're doing.